# Android PrintManager PageRange is null

Tags: android, printing

In my Android print class, sometimes I will meet in onWrite function the parameter of PageRange is null, it is a override function and the value is passed from Android framework, I want to find the cause why it is null sometimes(not 100%)? Is it a device issue? Has anybody met this? The code and log are below:

```
class PdfFragmentPrintDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter{
  public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {

    ........
    callback.onWriteFinished(pages);
  }
 .........


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pages cannot be empty
     at android.print.PrintManager$PrintDocumentAdapterDelegate$MyWriteResultCallback.onWriteFinished(PrintManager.java:961)
     at com.microsoft.pdfviewer.PdfFragmentPrint$PdfFragmentPrintDocumentAdapter$2.run(PdfFragmentPrint.java:265)
     at com.microsoft.pdfviewer.PdfFragmentPrint$PdfFragmentPrintDocumentAdapter.implementOnWriteInDedicatedThread(PdfFragmentPrint.java:278)
     at com.microsoft.pdfviewer.PdfFragmentPrint$PdfFragmentPrintDocumentAdapter.onWrite(PdfFragmentPrint.java:213)
     at android.print.PrintManager$PrintDocumentAdapterDelegate$MyHandler.handleMessage(PrintManager.java:792)
```

Comment: Because onWrite accept a cancel signal.

Comment: Does anyone know how to handle onWrite cancel? I call onWriteCancelled();but it still will execute onWriteFinished().

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly have to extract the pages yourself call `onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES})` and write the whole pdf. In this case, even when a page range is passed the system will then render and print only the pages that were selected.